# Combination of 2 templated constructors for class build with variadic templates. How?

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, factory, std-function

I created some small factory class. See the code below. The factory uses a simple map with a key and a class creator function. The challenge was that I wanted to use different signatures for the createInstance functions. With that, I could use different derived classes with different constructor signatures. So, I would be able to pass different values to the constructor of the classes.

Since I cannot store functions with different signatueres in `std::function` and finally in a `std::map`, I have written a short wrapper that "erases" the type parameter part. So, basically I can then store the function in a `std::function`, and finally in a `std::any`.

The code works fine. You can compile it and run it without problem.

There is also some test code attached.

Now my question:

I tried to come up with only **one** constructor in my class **"Creator"**. But I could **not** achieve that. In my opinion it should be possible. I would like to ask for your support to come up with a possible solution.

Please note: I am in the phase of refactoring. So the code is not yet "perfect".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <any>

// Some demo classes ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
struct Base {
    Base(int d) : data(d) {};
    virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Destructor Base\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Base\n"; }
    int data{};
};
struct Child1 : public Base {
    Child1(int d, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child1 " << d << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child1() { std::cout << "Destructor Child1\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child1: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child2 : public Base {
    Child2(int d, char c, long l) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child2 " << d << " " << c << " " << l << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child2() { std::cout << "Destructor Child2\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child2: " << data << "\n"; }
};
struct Child3 : public Base {
    Child3(int d, long l, char c, std::string s) : Base(d) { std::cout << "Constructor Child3 " << d << " " << l << " " << c << " " << s << "\n"; }
    virtual ~Child3() { std::cout << "Destructor Child3\n"; }
    virtual void print() { std::cout << "Print Child3: " << data << "\n"; }
};


using Ret = std::unique_ptr<Base>;

template <typename ... Args>
using Func = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Hide away the different signatures for std::function
class Creator
{
public:
    Creator() {}

    // I want to combine the follwong 2 constructors in one
    template<typename Function>
    Creator(Function&& fun) : Creator(std::function(fun)) {}
    template<typename ... Args>
    Creator(Func<Args...> fun) : m_any(fun) {}

    template<typename ... Args>
    Ret operator()(Args ... args)   { return std::any_cast<Func<Args...>>(m_any)(args...);  }
protected:
    std::any m_any;
};


template <class Child, typename ...Args>
std::unique_ptr<Base> createClass(Args...args) { return std::make_unique<Child>(args...); }

// The Factory ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
template <class Key>
class Factory
{
    std::map<Key, Creator> selector;
public:
    Factory(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, Creator>> il) : selector(il) {}

    template <typename ... Args>
    Ret createInstance(Key key, Args ... args) {
        if (selector.find(key) != selector.end()) {
            return selector[key](args ...);
        }
        else {
            return std::make_unique<Base>(0);
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Factory<int> factory { 
        {1, createClass<Child1, int, std::string>},
        {2, createClass<Child2, int, char, long>},
        {3, createClass<Child3, int, long, char, std::string>}
    };

    // Some test values
    std::string s1(" Hello1 "); std::string s3(" Hello3 ");
    int i = 1;  const int ci = 1;   int& ri = i;    const int& cri = i;   int&& rri = 1;

    std::unique_ptr<Base> b1 = factory.createInstance(1,   1, s1);
    std::unique_ptr<Base> b2 = factory.createInstance(2,   2, '2', 2L);
    std::unique_ptr<Base> b3 = factory.createInstance(3,   3, 3L, '3', s3);

    b1->print();
    b2->print();
    b3->print();
    b1 = factory.createInstance(2, 4, '4', 4L);
    b1->print();
    return 0;
}
```

So, again, I would like to get rid of the 2 constructors

```
    template<typename Function>
    Creator(Function&& fun) : Creator(std::function(fun)) {}

    template<typename ... Args>
    Creator(Func<Args...> fun) : m_any(fun) {}
```

and have only one in the end. How?

Sorry for the lengthy code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply removing the constructor taking the `std::function`?

```
template<typename Function>
Creator(Function&& fun) : m_any(std::function(fun)) {}
```

This will wrap `fun` only if it's not already a `std::function`. For cases if it's a `std::function` then it's a noop.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/ODClJq)

---

Looking at your code, you only use function pointers as your factory function. You could save yourself some indirections using function pointers directly instead of `std::function`, which is already a layer like `std::any`.

```
template <typename ... Args>
using Func = std::add_pointer_t<Ret(Args...)>;

// in you class:

template<typename Function, std::enable_if_t<std::is_pointer_v<Function>, int> = 0>
Creator(Function fun) : m_any(fun) {}
```

If you use that, in C++20 you can remove the ugly enable if and use a concept:

```
template<typename T>
concept FunctionPointer = requires(T t) {
    requires std::is_pointer_v<T>;
    requires std::is_function_v<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>;
    { std::function(t) };
};

// then in your class:

Creator(FunctionPointer auto fun) : m_any(fun) {}
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/E9VvIx)